# Python Awis API giving not IOError

Tags: python

I have installed https://github.com/muhuk/python-awis in order to get the url information from alexa.

I am using this

```
import awis
api = AwisApi(ACCESS_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
tree = api.url_info(("example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"), "Rank", "LinksInCount")
elem = tree.find("//{%s}StatusCode" % api.NS_PREFIXES["alexa"])
assert eenter code herelem.text == "Success"
```

When I try to run the script, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Python Scripts\Domains\alexa api\AlexaURL.py", line 3, in <module>
    tree = api.url_info(("example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"), "Rank", "LinksInCount")
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Python Scripts\Domains\alexa api\awis\__init__.py", line 121, in url_info
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]    return self.request(params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Python Scripts\Domains\alexa api\awis\__init__.py", line 91, in request
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 359, in open_http
    return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 372, in http_error
    result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 683, in http_error_401
    errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "C:\python27\lib\urllib.py", line 381, in http_error_default
    raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)
IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x022FD580>)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The response you get is "401 Unauthorized", which probably means that your ACCESS_ID and/or SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are not correct.

Also, make sure that you pass the two aforementioned keys as bytes and not strings, or you will get an error there as well.

You can use the str.encode function for that like:

```
 api = awis.AwisApi(str.encode(self.access_key_id),
                           str.encode(self.secret_access_key_id))
```

Otherwise your script is correct. I use it just like this and it works.

Comment: Thanks I will try this.  Quick question what do you mean make sure i pass them as bytes, do you have a example?

Comment: @mofoparrot I edited the answer with a code example you can use. Hope it helps.

Comment: @NikosSteiakakis i keep getting this response IOError: All 3 requests failed, latest response code is 403